# .prop method in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code but however it still shows an alert box saying `hello`.Why isn't the `prop` method not working? Isn't this supposed to get disabled and not pop an alert?

```
<button type="button" class="abc" onclick="alert('hello');">click me</button>
<script>
 $('.abc').prop('disabled',true);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4o8epvt2/

Comment: Not its working https://jsfiddle.net/4o8epvt2/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery loaded

Click the JavaScript settings menu and add the jQuery framework